# Emit from socket.io after a db query in node/express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a component which, when it mounts, makes a request to my server to get a (very long) list of names. In order for that to not hold up the rendering of my component (since it can only render with a non-empty list), I want to send it a series of much smaller lists using sockets, instead of the one long list with `res.send()` (which takes ~4 seconds).

To do this, I'm using socket.io in my express server, but I'm getting 404 errors. This is my setup:

**Client (component)**

```
    import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('trying to put on sock');
        const socket = socketIOClient();
        socket.on('names', data => console.log('data'));
    }
```

The parent of this component is the one that calls the `api/v1/names` route.

**Server**

```
    const express = require('express');    
    const socketIo = require('socket.io');
    const http = require('http');

    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    const io = socketIo(server);

    app.get('/api/v1/names', (req, res) => {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      getNames().then((result) => {
        // res.send({ result }); what I was doing before (~4 seconds)

        io.on('connection', (socket) => {
          console.log('New client connected');
          // chunk the results into 10 smaller arrays
          let final = false;
          const parts = _.chunk(result, 10);
          parts.forEach((part, pIx) => {
            if (pIx === parts.length - 1) final = true;
            // Will this be async or not? we shall see...
            socket.emit('names', { result: part, final });
          });
          socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('Client disconnected');
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

What ends up happening instead is this error in my console: `GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=123kj123b 404 (Not Found)`. The logs in the `io.on('connection')` never happen. The `trying to put on sock` log is seen, so I know it's trying to listen.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:4200');
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('event', function(data){});
socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
```

Need connect with server like this.